# Roll over counter skipping zero

Tags: c, counter, monthcalendar

Maybe an easy question, but I cannot get my head around it.

I'm doing some kind of a month counter, the idea is the user can press - or + and still reach the desired month:
for example I have:
Today is Feb so something like this
 The user press - 
 2 1 12 11 10 9 ......
 Some goes for +
The problem is I don't want the zero tobe displayed

```
SINT16 tempVal = pDate->month + upDown;
    if (tempVal < 0) {
        tempVal += (12+1);
    } 
    pDate->month % (12 + 1);
```

This is what i have come up with- it rolls over 12 and then 0 or 1 0 12 
But I want get rid of the zero. 
Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: `SINT16` -> `int16_t`

Comment: `a % b` is a number between `0` and `b-1`. If you wanted a number between `1` and `b`, what would you do?

Comment: If you want to *skip* the zero, the `if` conditional is off by one. If you correct that, you won't have to awkwardly add `12 + 1`.

Comment: molbdnilo - can you give an example

Comment: @Metio_1993 If I give you a number that is between 0 and 11, you can easily turn it into a number between 1 and 12. How can you do it?

Comment: @Metio_1993 And if `m` isn't negative, `m % 12` is a number between 0 and 11, so... (You were almost there.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is very unclear, but i'll try

```
SINT16 tempVal = pDate->month + upDown;
if (tempVal < 0) {
    /* if you are at negative 1 - assuming upDown is either (1,-1) */
    tempVal += (12); //just add the cycle value
} 

//pDate->month % (12 + 1);
pDate->month = (pDate->month % 12) + 1;//modulo by the cycle and then shift output
```

to be clear modulo 12 will output values (0 - 11) so the +1 should not be included in the modulo function

Answer (score 1):

if tempVal goes to zero then take month as 12 otherwise increase it by 1:

```
SINT16 tempVal = pDate->month + upDown;
    if (tempVal == 0) {
        pDate->month = 12;
    }//if month becomes more than 12,ie 13
    else if(tempVal %12 == 1)
    {
       pData->month = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        pDate->month = tempVal;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

By choosing your comparisons carefully, you can simplify the use of `'%'`. Instead of checking if `month = 12` or `month < 0`, check whether the increment causes `month > 12` or `month < 1`. Those are the points where a roll to `1` or `12` are required.

For example, in a generic function for incrementing / decrementing the month by some value `chg`, you simply add `chg` to the current month and then apply the test, correcting with `month = month % 12` where `month > 12` or by setting `month = month + 12` where `month < 1`, e.g.:

```
int monthchg (int *m, int chg)
{
    *m += chg;

    if (*m > 12)        /* if month > 12, roll to month % 12 */
        *m = *m % 12;
    else if (*m < 1)    /* if month < 1, add 12 to month */
        *m += 12;

    return *m;
}
```

A short example that puts the keyboard in non-canonical or raw mode and accepts `+/-` inputs to change the month or `q` to quit could be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <termios.h>

typedef struct {
    struct termios old;     /* orig keyboard settings   */
    struct termios new;
} kbmode;

kbmode *setkbmode (kbmode *k);
kbmode *restorekbmode (kbmode *k);

int monthchg (int *m, int chg)
{
    *m += chg;

    if (*m > 12)        /* if month > 12, roll to month % 12 */
        *m = *m % 12;
    else if (*m < 1)    /* if month < 1, add 12 to month */
        *m += 12;

    return *m;
}

int main (void) {

    kbmode kb = { .old = {0} };
    int dir, month = 6;

    setkbmode (&kb);        /* set kbd in raw-unbufered mode */

    printf ("enter +/- to inc/decrement month ('q' to quit)\n");
    for (;;) {
        printf ("\n  month : %2d : ", month);
        fflush (stdout);
        dir = getchar();

        if (dir == '+')
            monthchg (&month, 1);
        else if (dir == '-')
            monthchg (&month, -1);
        else if (dir == 'q')
            break;
        else
            puts ("invalid input - try again.");
    }
    putchar ('\n');

    restorekbmode (&kb);    /* restore original kbd settings */

    return 0;
}

/* set keyboard in raw-unbufered mode */
kbmode *setkbmode (kbmode *k)
{
    if (tcgetattr (0, &(k->old))) { /* save orig settings   */
        fprintf (stderr, "setkbmode() error: tcgetattr failed.\n");
        return NULL;
    }   /* copy old to new */
    k->new = k->old;

    k->new.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON);  /* new kbd flags */
    k->new.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
    k->new.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;
    if (tcsetattr (0, TCSANOW, &(k->new))) {
        fprintf (stderr, "setkbmode() error: tcgetattr failed.\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    return k;
}

kbmode *restorekbmode (kbmode *k)
{
    /* reset original keyboard  */
    if (tcsetattr (0, TCSANOW, &(k->old))) {
        fprintf (stderr, "restorekbmode() error: tcsetattr failed.\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    return k;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/month_roll
enter +/- to inc/decrement month ('q' to quit)

  month :  6 : -
  month :  5 : -
  month :  4 : -
  month :  3 : -
  month :  2 : -
  month :  1 : -
  month : 12 : -
  month : 11 : -
  month : 10 : +
  month : 11 : +
  month : 12 : +
  month :  1 : +
  month :  2 : -
  month :  1 : -
  month : 12 : -
  month : 11 : -
  month : 10 : +
  month : 11 : +
  month : 12 : +
  month :  1 : +
  month :  2 : +
  month :  3 : q
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to keep your month counter in [0, 11] format internally in the code, using modulo(12) for wrapping around. This is simple and makes for easy to understand code.
Then write a function for mapping that internal representation [0, 11] to something a user would want to see, i.e [1, 12], whenever you print or in some way display the value to the user.

```
int16_t display_month(int16_t month)
{
    return month + 1;
}
```

In this case it's dead simple to return month + 1, but in a more general case of mapping a count of N to something that doesn't match [0, N-1] I would use an array to store this mapping. That way the mapping could really be anything, doesn't have to be in order and doesn't event need to be integers.

```
int16_t display_month(int16_t month)
{
    static int16_t index_to_month_map[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12}; 
    return index_to_month_map[month];
}
```